# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: adapter is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, adapter

I'm attempting to convert a CLI script I've made in JS/Typescript into a Chrome Extension. The CLI program works perfectly but when I compile it into a Chrome extension, I'm getting the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: adapter is not a function

It has something to do with the "trading-view-recommends-parser-nodejs" library I'm using which calls TradingView and parses the response in JSON.

This is the snippet in my lib.ts file:

```
  const result = await new TradingViewScan(
    SCREENERS_ENUM['crypto'],
    EXCHANGES_ENUM['BINANCE'],
    bettingPair,
    INTERVALS_ENUM['5m'],
  ).analyze();
  var obj = JSON.stringify(result.summary);
  var recommendation = JSON.parse(obj)
```

[Full Screenshot of Error in Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2sWY.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong considering it works fine in CLI.